# Join event by date and time from two datasets

Tags: sql, azure, date, join, time

I have two tables from two different systems that record the same event (phone call). The join fields are Operator, ScriptID, Date and Time.

The issue I have is that the date and time may vary between the two systems by a number of seconds, and sometimes this will result in the date differing.

For example

```
EventA in Table 1 occurs at = 23h59:55 15 Nov 2017
EventA in Table 2 occurs at = 00h00:07 16 Nov 2017
```

The data has been pulled into a cloud data warehouse which is hosted in Microsoft Azure and uses SQL and TSQL.

```
Sample Date from Table 1
Operator    Call Date Time  ScriptID
Operator A  4/11/2017 23:48:07  Script 1
Operator A  4/11/2017 23:48:13  Script 2
Operator A  4/11/2017 23:54:56  Script 3
Operator C  5/11/2017 0:03:18   Script 4
Operator A  5/11/2017 0:04:15   Script 5
```

Sample Date from Table 2

```
ScriptID    Session Date Time   Operator 
Script 1    4/11/2017 23:48:06  Operator A
Script 2    4/11/2017 23:49:20  Operator A
Script 3    4/11/2017 23:50:48  Operator A
Script 4    4/11/2017 23:59:41  Operator C
Script 5    5/11/2017 0:03:35   Operator A
```

Required Result

```
Operator    ScriptID    Call Date Time  Session Date Time   
Operator A  Script 1    4/11/2017 23:48:07  4/11/2017 23:48:06  
Operator A  Script 2    4/11/2017 23:48:13  4/11/2017 23:49:20  
Operator A  Script 3    4/11/2017 23:54:56  4/11/2017 23:50:48  
Operator C  Script 4    5/11/2017 0:03:18   4/11/2017 23:59:41  Different Dates
Operator A  Script 5    5/11/2017 0:04:15   5/11/2017 0:03:35
```

I initally joined the tables by only Operator, ScriptID and Date and then did a variance calculation in time and found the minimum time variance using a partition of Operator, ScriptID and Date.

This works except for the the cases where the date differs and due to the size of the datasets the partition is causing performance issues.

Is there a way to create a field in both tables that would overcome this issue and allow for a logical join to be created by date and time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is an absolute requirement to specify which database you are using. date & time functions vary enormously between dbms vendors. add a tag for the dbms please. a few sample rows would be useful as well

Comment: By the way, if performance is the main issue here, can you modify these tables at all? (e.g. to add indexes)  AND can you provide the DDL for both tables? (showing all indexes)